# libusb access denial (not udev, not apparmor)

Tags: usb, udev, apparmor

I am getting a:

```
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/007: Operation not permitted
```

error when trying to pass through a USB disk to the virtual machine. Traditional "why it does not work" explanation is lack of propper udev rules or app-armor denials. As for the first I have created a udev rule:

```
user@hostname:~# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/WD.rules
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1058", ATTRS{idProduct}=="25e2", MODE="0777"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1058", ATTRS{idProduct}=="25e2",  MODE="0777"
SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1058", ATTRS{idProduct}=="25e2", MODE="0777"
```

Just to verify the udev rule loads:

```
root@hostname:/home/user/snap/sosumi/common# ls -l  /dev/bus/usb/001/007 
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 189, 6 Apr 19 13:43 /dev/bus/usb/001/007
```

as for the AppArmor I have pushed the sosumi into the aa-complain (AFAIK this should make it complain but not block anything):

```
[ 1470.031181] kauditd_printk_skb: 79 callbacks suppressed
[ 1470.031184] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:364): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/sys/bus/usb/devices/" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.031340] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:365): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/c189:512" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.031479] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:366): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/+usb:6-0:1.0" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.031595] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:367): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/c189:256" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.032276] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:368): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/c189:129" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.032442] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:369): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/+usb:1-1.4:1.0" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.032566] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:370): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/+usb:1-2:1.0" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.032683] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:371): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/c189:0" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.032811] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:372): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/+usb:2-1:1.0" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1470.032937] audit: type=1400 audit(1618833664.681:373): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.sosumi.sosumi" name="/run/udev/data/c189:3" pid=11370 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

What else can I do?

Comment: also does not work when running sosumi as root (but this may call something from other user perhaps?).

Comment: is this a VirtualBox VM or some other virtualization layer?

Comment: This is sosumi, which essentially runs a bash script with qemu.

Comment: There is a chance that "snap connections" were the issue, as this is another thing that may limit access to the hardware: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-connections-command/4296    However, I am unable to test it as I am done with this project (instead of mounting the USB disk I re-partitioned it, created the img of an important piece and mounted that).